# Learning about hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to figure out how to print just the key in a Hash right now. I'm still new to this and I'm missing something on how to just print the key. My code so far:

```
shopping_list = {
    'milk' => false,
    'eggs' => false,
    'jalapenos' => true
}

puts "Here is your shopping list!"
shopping_list.each do |key|
    puts "- #{key}"
end
```

My output:

```
Here is your shopping list!
- ["milk", false]
- ["eggs", false]
- ["jalapenos", true]
```

I just want to value to print out like:

```
Here is your shopping list!
- milk
- eggs
```

Eventually, I would like to leave out the true shopping item, in this instance, it would already be purchased. I would like to print out what I still need to buy first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get values you want by combining `#reject`, `#keys` and `#each` methods like below:

```rb
shopping_list.reject { |key, value| value }.keys.each do |key|
  puts "- #{key}"
end
```

As Cary Swoveland mentioned, the code above was created temporary arrays. If you don't want to created those, you can use the code below:

```rb
shopping_list.each do |key, value|
  puts "- #{key}" if value == false
end
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland it can be improved, `shopping_list.each { |k,v| puts "- #{k}" unless v }` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
shopping_list = {
    'milk' => false,
    'eggs' => false,
    'jalapenos' => true
}

puts "Here is your shopping list!"
for key in shopping_list.keys()
    puts "- #{key}"
end
```

My output.

```
Here is your shopping list!
- milk
- eggs
- jalapenos
```

Comment: This does not return the result you specified in the question.

Comment: I know, it was a step on my way to figuring it out. It's actually one of the other things I needed it to do at the end.